# Python requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(): Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python

(1) PC OS: Win10 20H2
(2) IDE: PyCharm 2021.3
(3) Python version: 3.10
(4) The requests package version: 2.27.1
(5) The software (may cause the problem) on pc: Clash for Windows(v 0.18.2)

(6) The code is following:

```
import requests
create_account_url = "https://opentdb.com/api.php"
para = {
    "amount": 10,
    "difficulty": "medium",
    "type": "boolean"
}

response = requests.get(create_account_url, params=para)
response.raise_for_status()
print(response.json())
```

The problem is:

(1)Running the code above when I open the button(System Proxy) in Clash, the error is:

```
 "requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='opentdb.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api.php?amount=10&difficulty=medium&type=boolean (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

(2) After I turn off the button (System Proxy) in Clash, the running is ok and no error.

But the proxy is necessary when I need to access some sites in China.

Please help. Thank you!